# using sql variable in sum() like this--sum(@wokao) cause unpredicted result

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, sum, user-defined-functions

Query 1)

```
Select * From test;

-----------
|no1|no2|
----+------
|1  |   1 |
|2  |   2 |
|3  |   3 |
|4  |   4 |
|5  |   5 |
----+------
```

Query 2)

```
select @wokao:= (no1 + no2), @wokao from test group by no1;

2   2
4   4
6   6
8   8
10  10
```

Query 3)

```
select @wokao:= (no1 + no2), sum(@wokao) from test group by no1;

2   null
4   2
6   4
8   6
10  8
```

The result of last SQL query is confusing. Why doesn't it output something like the second query result?

I ask this question because I searched keyword of "sum() sql variable" in google and stackoverflow and got nothing. And I got this problem when I wrote a SQL query at work to query a transaction information using SQL variable in SUM() and a lot of subquery.

I really appreciate anyone could explain this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [MYSQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/user-variables.html)

> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement.For other statements, such as SELECT, you might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed.

In the following statement, you might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an assignment second:

```
SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ...;
```

**However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined**.

So in your second Query, `@wokao` is first evaluate with calculation `@wokao:= (no1 + no2)`, then display the result While in third query, first display the value of `sum(@wokao)` then Calculate, and because at first, value of `@wokao`  is null, that's why its first display null, and then after add subsequent values to it.

Comment: Thank you. Your anwser enlighten me!